# What do the numbers next to recent searches mean?

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

On *Jobs* on the right side is your recent searches. There I noticed these numbers:

[image: Screenshot]

At first I thought the numbers meant the number of results, but clicking on it yields strange results. For example, the first one returns 1021 Java architect jobs, but the number said 860 next to it. Upon clicking it, it goes away.

Comment: That's a weird hand-drawn red circle...

Comment: Tis the season to be jolly....

Comment: I've just noticed that the weird red circles are actually santa's hat.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Last I checked it was not monday!

Comment: Agree that this can be confusing. We're taking a look at how we can make it clear that the number represents new jobs for that search.

Answer (score 9):

The number is in HTML elements with `-badge jobs-sidebar-new-jobs-link` and `jobs-sidebar-new-search-count` as classes.

Based on that, and your observation of the numbers disappearing when you click on it, I'm gonna guess that it's the number of new results since you last executed that search query.

Comment: If this is the case I don't think its very helpful.  To me its more confusing...I clicked on the first one and got 1020 results but the number showed 860.  Without a tooltip or what have you I see no purpose in this rather more confusion.