# Sort by is lost as I go through jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The sort by drop down should retain its value as you search through jobs.
Imagine you search for a job with the keywords "javascript engineer".  The system returns say 10 listings.  You mark the sort by salary say.  You go to the first job listing read it and then click "back to search" to go look at the next one.  At this point the sorting is reset and you've lost your spot.

**Please maintain the value on this field.**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to jobs
2. Enter "javascript engineer" in the search box
3. Do a sort by salary
4. Click first listing
5. Click the link to go back to the job listing search:

   > [image: Screenshot]
6. Sort is lost.

Comment: That's a weird hand-drawn red circle...

Comment: Tis the season to be jolly...

Comment: I've just noticed that the weird red circles are actually a snowman.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Last I checked it was not MONDAY!

Comment: [Déjà vu](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340059/what-do-the-numbers-next-to-recent-searches-mean).

Comment: @MarounMaroun - There should be some hat awarded just for us 3.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Yeah, some hat from last  ̶M̶o̶n̶d̶a̶y̶ year would fit to this déjà-vu.

Comment: @honk If you edit the previous post, we will give you a hat as well.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Done :)

Comment: Many of us feel lost and out of sorts as we go through jobs.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, could you please include a [Déjà vu](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340156/sort-by-is-lost-as-i-go-through-jobs) link in the aforementioned post's comments section ? My infinite loop crazyness is broken at one iteration and that looks like a real bug to me.

Comment: Also, there is a [pluralization bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug) under Job Description -- should be "retailer**s**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to report this! it's been fixed and deployed